# Docker images that don't contain a package manager

Tags: linux, filesystems, java, docker, chroot

I typically think of docker containers as executable processes that get to carry with them little bits of "environment", such that nothing needs to be installed on the docker host. For instance, a java jar along with a jre.

In order to install the jre, we might start with an ubuntu base box and then use aptitude to install it. However, though we effectively require a package manager in order to configure the dependencies (a jre, in this case) for our app, I don't think it is strictly required to execute our app.

Which raises a question that is too far down the rabbit hole to be of practical concern, but still an intellectual curiosity: Is it feasible to install dependencies in a docker image, without also including the package manager in the built image?

Looking into how this might be accomplished for chroots, it appears to be hard or impossible. On the face of it, this challenge seems solvable (for instance, if I build a java application with gradle or maven, I don't have to include the gradle or maven binary in my published program), so I'm also curious to know why it appears to have no easy solution. Is anyone working on the problem of installing dependencies into a docker image (or a chroot, for that matter)? If not, why not?

(The solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/633650/770922) and solution 2 from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/193704/770922) require installing a package manager into a chroot, which doesn't address my question of how to get the package manager out of the docker image. Solution 1 from the second  deals with building from source (I think?) which isn't exactly what I'm looking for either).